# Working with GraphQL Field Type of Objects

Tags: javascript, graphql

I think I am missing something in the docs but I am not sure how to handle objects as the type withing a new GraphQLObjectType. I am looking to set up the queries for weather data from [this sample data](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22), and I am not sure how to handle the nested objects. I currently have:

```
// Creating a Type for the Weather Object
const WeatherType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Weather',
    fields: () => ({
        weather: { type: GraphQLObject? },
    })
});
```

I am looking to get specific with the queries and set up the structure to specify more select data like:

```
// Creating a Type for the Weather Object
const WeatherType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Weather',
    fields: () => ({
        weather: { 
            main: { type: GraphQLString },
            // And so on
        },
    })
});
```

Are there any references to examples of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When constructing a schema with nested custom types, you just set the type of the field to a reference of your other created type:

```
const WeatherType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Weather',
  fields: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
    }
    main: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    }
    description: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    }
    icon: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    }
  }
})

const MainType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Main',
  fields: {
    temp: {
      type: GraphQLFloat,
    }
    pressure: {
      type: GraphQLFloat,
    }
    humidity: {
      type: GraphQLFloat,
    }
    tempMin: {
      type: GraphQLFloat,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.temp_min
    }
    tempMax: {
      type: GraphQLFloat,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.temp_max
    }
  }
})

const WeatherSummaryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'WeatherSummary',
  fields: {
    weather: {
      type: new GraphQLList(WeatherType),
    }
    main: {
      type: MainType,
    }
  }
})
```

Be careful when molding existing JSON responses into GraphQL schemas -- it's easy to get burned by differences in structure. For example, the `main` field in your sample response is an object, but the `weather` field is actually an array, so we have to wrap it in `GraphQLList` when specifying the type for the field.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the explanation. I knew there was something funky with my thought process.

Comment: @JoshBowden No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if you feel like it answered your question sufficiently.